# Difficulty centering images on html+css site

Tags: html, css

I created a website for a friend: http://personaltrainerffm.de/

and the logos underneath (see pictures) won't be shown centered. Also when browsing with a mobile device, it will get screwed. Can you please help?

THANK YOU VERY MUCH in advance

[Screenshot on smartphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V00y1.png)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those logo containers (`.container-erfahr ul li`) all have a `float: left` setting in their CSS. Since the second one is higher than the third one, the fourth one is positioned below the third one (i.e. right of the second one) in the mobile view - that's the way floats work.

To fix this and center them, erase the `float:left` and define them all as `display: inline-block`. To center the elements, add `text-align: center` to their container element `.container-erfahr`.

These are the *changed* rules:

```
.container-erfahr ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px solid lightgray;
    list-style: none;
}

.container-erfahr {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Johannes! Can I buy you a coffee? :-)

Comment: I am up for it, if you are in Vienna ;-)

Comment: Hmmm... just in Frankfurt by now. Thank you very much Johannes, it has been a great help!